# How do I protected my sensitive data (financial) from website/CRM programmers?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema, alter-table

As a company owner, I need to protect my sensitive data from my website/CRM programmers. I know I can scramble DB values with a simple script but it needs to be applied manually all the time and when they need to work deeply on DB structure they can get annoyed not having full control of the actual DB data.

How are the pro solving this issue?

Comment: Are you a developer or DBA?

Comment: You mention scramble - is your need to scrub production data during a copy to a test environment?

Comment: You really cannot, so hire only people you do trust - and have contracts and NDAs in place. A developer can always access data if they want to - they control the application. There is [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) but that's more when you don't trust the hosting.

Comment: Normally you would have a test site and a production site. On SQL Server you can also use Column Level Security, although could cause problems in testing. Or you could use Data Masking. Neither of these options will really stand up to a determined malicious user.

Comment: @Charlieface: what is `column level security`?

Comment: @J.D.: I'm the DBA

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#special-considerations-for-column-level-permissions and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Practically speaking, you're quite limited in what you can do - especially without significant expense, which is usually not tolerable to those seeking a solution.

An analogy I sometimes use, is that it's like trying to stop the secretary seeing your files, when the point of having a secretary is for somebody skilled to handle the filing on your behalf.

A company with very serious and legitimate concerns might force the majority of development to be done with false test data in development environments, with only one (or a limited number) of trusted senior staff being able to access sensitive data in bulk or transfer new developments to live operation.

The overheads of multiple people doing what one person could do for themselves, and various other overheads like devising test data, setting up and maintaining distinct development environments etc., are just the cost of doing business for larger organisations.

But in all organisations, you have to accept that there are at least some technical staff who have full access to data, because they are responsible for provisioning and overseeing the facilities which collect, store, and process that data.

And in smaller organisations with only a small complement of technical staff, the technical staff who have that full access to data may well be all the technical staff.